# Path to US board certification for international medical doctor

Tags: graduate-admissions, career-path, advisor, united-states, medicine

I would like to get a board certification in order to practice is US as a doctor.

I am graduating in October in Italy and I am aware that before getting a residency in US I should pass USMLE exams STEP 1, 2CK, 2CS.

Taking into account I don't have any contact in US, **which is the best route I should follow in order to maximize my chances of getting a residency**?

I am sure that getting outstanding marks in USMLE exams could help a lot but it isn't a guarantee, nor sufficient to be hired.

What about trying to get an observership, PhD program or similar.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "_the best route_"? The shortest time? A good medical doctor eventually? Or something else?

Comment: Also, do you want just practice medicine in the US or doing medical research after you get the residency?

Comment: Best route --> shortest time to get a residency. Sure, a good speciality doctor but if you can't get into a residency it's impossible.

I would like to do medical research during the residency, after that I think I will just practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a mainly non-academic career. It **may** be on-topic on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), but please check their guidelines before posting.

Comment: Close voters and about-to-vote-to-close voters, please see [this meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/850/546)

Comment: I would view the US residency system as medicine's equivalent of a postdoc: a combination of training and practice undertaken after the terminal degree. My impression is that they are quite academic in character: often done at a university's teaching hospital, where supervising physicians have the title "Professor". I think questions about residencies are on topic, though I am not sure how many users we have in medicine who could answer.

Comment: @scaaahu: I didn’t realise that *residency* is a term referring to a stage of medical education (instead I thought that it referred to a doctor’s office, surgery or whatever) and thus the only thing linking the question to academia was the mention of the possiblility to get into a PhD program. Retracting my close vote.

Comment: For others who may be unfamiliar: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_(medicine)

Comment: Just checking--you've gone through the [AMA pages](http://www.ama-assn.org/ama/pub/about-ama/our-people/member-groups-sections/international-medical-graduates.page?) on international medical graduates (IMG)?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, I've already read it some time ago. Thanks for your input!